# How to calculate the duration in time series data with R?

Tags: r, time-series

```
mydata<-data.frame(t=lubridate::ymd(c("2018-1-1","2018-1-2","2018-1-5","2018-1-6","2018-1-7","2018-1-8")),x=c(3,1,1,3,1,3))
ggplot(mydata,aes(t,x))+geom_line()
```

[image]
In this case, I want know the duration of x < 2, (which is 5 including "1-2,1-3,1-4,1-5,1-7").How can I do this using R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this using `dplyr::lag`?

```
# Calculate time difference to previous date
mydata$diff <- mydata$t - dplyr::lag(mydata$t);

as.numeric(sum(mydata$diff[mydata$x < 2]))
#[1] 5
```

Or using a full `tidyverse` approach:

```
require(tidyverse);
mydata %>% 
    mutate(diff = t - lag(t)) %>%
    summarise(duration = sum(diff[x < 2]));
#    duration
#1   5 days
```

---

### Sample data

```
mydata<-data.frame(
    t = lubridate::ymd(c("2018-1-1", "2018-1-2", "2018-1-5", "2018-1-6", "2018-1-7", "2018-1-8")),
    x = c(3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3));
```